# copy and autorelease in enumeration

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, for-loop, enumeration

I am trying to change the contents of an array while enumeration. To avoid the warning ,"the array was mutated while being enumerated" i made a copy of the array and done the autorelease like this-

```
int iKeyArrayCount=0;
        for(NSString *keyEntity in [[keyArray copy]autorelease])
        {
            [keyArray replaceObjectAtIndex:iKeyArrayCount withObject:[keyEntity stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:kMPVTBlankString]];
            [keyArray replaceObjectAtIndex:iKeyArrayCount withObject:[keyEntity stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
            iKeyArrayCount++;
        }
```

My confusion is regarding the enumeration over that copy of keyArray. While enumeration is it like , a copy of keyArray is formed each time the for loop executes? Or only one copy of that keyArray is formed during the whole process of enumeration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that code snippet `[[keyArray copy] autorelease]` is executed once only, and the result is used at the object being iterated.

In other words, "only one copy of that keyArray is formed during the whole process of enumeration" is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to copy the whole array for this. You could also just use a regular for-loop instead of the enumeration:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [keyArray count]; i++)
{
    NSString *keyEntity = [keyArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *newKeyEntity = [keyEntity stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@" "];
    newKeyEntity = [newKeyEntity stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    [keyArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:newKeyEntity];
}
```

Things may get dirty if you start adding/deleting objects in the loop, but as long as you just replace them this is just fine.

As you may have already noticed that `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` is useless in your example, since you replace it in the next line once again.

Comment: I just wanted to avoid 'objectAtIndex' property of array. That's why I used enhanced for loop , instead of normal for loop. I also got suggestion regarding the functionality can be achieved this way...NSMutableArray *keyArrayTemp=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  for(NSString *keyEntity in keyArray)
  {
   [keyArrayTemp addObject:[[keyEntity stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:kMPVTBlankString]];
  }
  [keyArray setArray:keyArrayTemp];
  [keyArrayTemp release];